# Magento and Wordpress - Synchronizing menu across both platforms, issue with cookie

Tags: wordpress, magento, multilingual

I am using the [Magento WordPress Integration](http://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/) plugin to call blocks from a parallel Magento installation in order to pull the appropriate menu blocks from Magento.

This is working very well except for one thing, the sites are multilingual.

I have inserted some code in Wordpress so that when the language is changed, it changes the store cookie to the appropriate language, in hopes of ensuring that Magento loads the menu in the right language.

This works perfectly except it requires, for some reason, two clicks before it loads the correct language. I can see in the web inspector that the 'store' cookie is set to the right language, but the plugin seems to be loading the Magento content before this happens somehow.

I'm really at a loss for what to do besides separating the menus and having them manually coded between systems. I was in [discussion](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multilingual-wpmagento-menu-does-not-load-proper-language-until-next-reload) with the actual developer of the plugin but he was unable to think of a solution himself (unfortunately the discussion was terminated when I asked for the possibility of contracting some support).

In any case, if anyone has any idea how to go about this I would so deeply appreciate it as it seems no one out there has found a solution for what I would have imagined was a rather typical setup.

--

edit: this is what I've written so far and am trying to get to work. It pulls the language string from the URL and then sets the `store` cookie. By looking at the [Plugin API/Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) it is the first thing that occurs in the load order. I do have a must-use plugin and can confirm it works, but also I've tried hooking it to registered_taxonomy, post type etc... For some bizarre reason it still doesn't work until the second click even though it happens far before the theme or the regular plugins load.

```
function set_store_cookie() {
    if( preg_match("(/(de|en|jp)/)",$_SERVER[REDIRECT_URL],$m)) {
        $pbCurrentLanguage = $m[1];
    } else {
      $currentLanguage = "en";
    }
    setcookie('store', $currentLanguage, time()+(60 * 60 * 24 * 1), COOKIEPATH, '.domain.com', false);
  }
add_action('registered_post_type', 'set_store_cookie');
```

--

**Edit 2:**
After extensive talk with Mihai below, we discussed a number of things but found primarily that **no matter what, if the `store` cookie is set, Wordpress loads the language specified by the cookie** even if statically calling `$app = Mage::app('desired_lang', 'store');`

This gets really confusing because it falls into the same issue as before: if the cookie is set, Wordpress fails to load the appropriate Magento language until the second refresh.

I've solved this in the meantime by deleting the cookie every time Wordpress is loaded, but this seems really to be an non-ideal solution. It is so baffling to me that even calling `Mage::app` statically loads the wrong language and is overridden by the cookie (and on the next load too)

Comment: The code you inserted is most likely modifying the cookie after the plugin is reading it, which would explain why it takes another refresh for the cookie to be read.  Try seeing if you can modify the store cookie before it's read by the plugin.

Comment: @Axel I just edited my answer to try to give more clarity, I assumed the same issue too but can't seem to find a solution, as far as I can tell it loads far earlier than the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The `Magento` `==>` `WordPress` bridge plugin initializes `Magento` at some point. At that point `Magento` can be loaded by specifying which `website` or which `storeview` you want to load.

This happens in the plugin file: wp-content/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/mwi.php on line 53 where you have the following code:

```
$app = Mage::app(self::getValue('websitecode','base'), 'website');
```

The first parameter (`self::getValue('websitecode','base')`) fetches the website code (short name) of the website to be loaded. The second parameter specifies the fact that the first parameter is a website code not a storeview code.

You can rewrite that line as such:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['storeviewcode'])) {
    /**
     *     Loads a particular storeview that you specify in
     * $_SESSION['storeviewcode'].
     */
    $app = Mage::app($_SESSION['storeviewcode'], 'store');
}
else {
    /**
     *     Falls back to default behavior.
     */
    $app = Mage::app(self::getValue('websitecode','base'), 'website');
}
```

I assume you know but for completeness Magento storeviews are usually used for translations, they have the specific locale associated with them.

All you need to do is:

- Find out during which WordPress event (hook) is Magento being loaded;
- Find out which event occurs right before Magento is being loaded;
- Write some code that initializes `$_SESSION['storeviewcode']` with a valid storeviewcode;
- Attach the code to the proper event (hook);
- Make sure the WordPress languages correspond to the correct storeviewcode;

Comment: Thank you for your response, I feel like I'm really getting closer here with a bit more understanding of where WP pulls in the Magento blocks. I'm really confused though, I'm even trying to put the store-cookie/session code right in the function above (right before `$app = Mage::app($_SESSION['storeviewcode'], 'store');` and it still seems to be pulling in the wrong store. I have even tried using a static store code `de`. The store view code is correct: http://cloud.alanwoo.ca/nlSd/52uAwo6K Even echoing the store code shows the correct code & inspecting the cookie is correct!

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with the cookie. I did not suggest using a cookie for this.

Comment: The reason for that is that cookies are "set" during the current PHP execution but they are only read by the next PHP execution.

Comment: I know, sorry I used a cookie, I adjusted your code to look at the cookie instead. ^^ Ah. I see. I will give it a shot. One moment.

Comment: You don't even need to use the session variables. You can use any global variable. $_COOKIE and $_SESSION are just super global variables with some special behavior.

Comment: Ok, for some reason, even using this static code loads the 'english' blocks: `$app = Mage::app('de', 'store');`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34898/discussion-between-waffl-and-mihai-stancu)

Comment: Is `de` the correct `core_store`.`code`? Check your database in the `core_store` table.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the question just yet, but I can't leave a comment either. However, could you confirm to me the cookie settings you've used in the admin area of Magento? (System > Config > Web)

Answer (score 0):

OK. Well Mihai, James (plugin author) and I spent hours chatting and trying endless possible solutions and none worked.

No matter what, **Magento kept overriding any manually requested locale with the cookie value**.

The issue is that *the correct cookie value was never read until the subsequent reload*.

My initial solution, as in the edit, was to unset the cookie each time Wordpress was loaded (not ideal) and manually call the locale via `Mage::app`.

Finally, I decided to look at it from a PHP standpoint rather than Magento/WP after Mihai mentioned how frustrating session/cookie implementation can be in PHP and came across this thread: http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4332059.htm

In the end it was a simple one-liner of adding:

`$_COOKIE['store'] = 'new_locale'`

after `setcookie(...)` to ensure the current cookie variable matches that of set cookie without requiring a second page load. This code was hooked into Wordpress via `add_action('muplugins_loaded', 'set_store_cookie');`, the earliest possible in Wordpress' action order.

No modifications were, in the end, necessary to Magento, Wordpress nor the WPI Plugin.

While it doesn't solve the question of why Magento was overriding manual app calls with the cookie, it does work properly now finally. It appears there is actually a bug with Magento: https://gist.github.com/Vinai/1205913 - even though this diff didn't correct the behaviour either.

Endless thanks Mihai and James, this was such a painful issue to try to sort out.

Comment: I mentioned this at some point: the $_COOKIE array gets loaded on the next page load. If you want access to it in the current page load you need to set its contents manually.